# PHP: Create dynamic hyperlink from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, hyperlink, href

I'm very new to PHP & MySQL databases and was wondering how to create a random hyperlink in the text content pulled from the database.

It's a blog type website and I would like to make certain words in the paragraph refer to different websites: is that possible?

I know I can do something like this:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testblog ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
$content = $row['content'];
$href = $row['href'];
?>
    <p> <a href="<?php echo $href; ?>"> <?php echo $content; ?> </a> </p>
```

The issue with the above format is that the whole paragraph is a hyperlink whereas I prefer individual words and sometimes I may not even need to refer to a website.

Any help or simply pointing me in the right direct will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: then yank apart the `$row['content']` string and wrap any words you want in links. Basically what you've got now, but on a word-by-word basis, instead of an "everything" basis.

Comment: You must have some sort of criteria for the text you want to display. First X number of characters, words? First sentence?

Comment: look this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how when pulling the content from a database. Every blog entry won't be the same and the hyperlink word will be random. I get how to do it with regular HTML but there are going to be a lot of entries on the webpage hence i'm using a database.

Comment: Okay Dave, let say I want the first sentence or word to be a hyperlink would that mean I would create a column for the first sentence/word in my database for every blog entry which will correlate to a href column followed by the rest of the blog entry?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is not PHP and is actually a Javascript thing.

You need to target specific words in the page body and replace them with a link. You can use the JKavascript replace function.

```
$("#myDiv").html().replace(/facebook/g, '<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>');
```

Then just repeat this for all of the links you want to add. The `g` means that it will selector all links in the div `id="myDiv"`

If you wanted to do this for a random word you could make an array of words in php and then choose one using `rand()` and then echo that into various parts of the Javascript. Example to follow

**PHP**

```
$word = array('facebook', 'twitter', 'john', 'mary'); // array of words

$i = rand(0, count($word)-1); // generate random number size of the array
$randword = "$word[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random word was chosen */
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#myDiv").html().replace(/<?php echo $ranword; ?>/g, '<a href="http://www.thiswebsite.com"><?php echo $ranword; ?></a>');
```

Or something like this.

Comment: You can do the exact same thing in PHP too.

Comment: @FabienWarniez Really? How?

Comment: @AdamBrown I see the logic but i'm not to familiar with javascript as yet. I do think based on your example that this might be the solution. Just curious is there not a way to enter text and code into a database ex. `$row['content']` but when shown on the webpage it shows all text and none of the code?

Comment: @user3272514 Sorry could you rephrase that last part, I didn't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: @user3272514 Do you mean to ONLY enter code into the body of text WHEN it is on the webpage? Yes, Javascript.

Comment: @AdamBrown Example in my database in column 'content' I enter: "Please like us on '<a href="facebook.com/1234">facebook</a>'" But when you see it on my webpage you don't see the `<a>` tags and the word facebook is a live link... I think you answered it already and I have to look into javascript.

Comment: @user3272514 If you want to store html in your database and then echo it onto a page whilst keeping the format of the html you should have no problem. I made something a long while back where I `echoed` html into `<p></p>` tags and the browser treats it like a regular webpage. The only problem you may have is if you want to insert html into the database, you may need to encode it.. http://htmlentities.net/

Comment: @user3272514 also you don't need to put `$row['content']` into another variable before echoing it.

Comment: @AdamBrown using regexp's.

Comment: @FabienWarniez You're completely right, I'd forgotten about `preg_replace()`!